# Testing AnkoComponents and mocking AnkoContext

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm writing an Android application in Kotlin.
I also use the [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) view library to replace xml with programmatic view creations.

I'd like to write specs for my views  (which are AnkoComponents).

Is there an accepted methodology for doing this?
I can't seem to find any information on specs + anko by googling or looking at the Anko docs.

Specifically, I'd like to test the `createView(ui : AnkoContext<T>)` method.

More specifically (and what I'm hoping will be answered by asking this question), is how do I mock out an `AnkoContext<T>` which I can pass to `createView` in my test?

Comment: Why do you want to mock `AnkoContext`? You can create it normally in tests using the `AnkoContext.create()` function.